# fail2ban doesn't match anything

Tags: 10.04, openssh, fail2ban

I'm working on a new build of my FTP server and I can't get the ssh part of fail2ban to match anything. Manually checking with the regex command shows nothing. Pam and proftpd are working fine, just not ssh.

Any ideas? Anyone already solved it, maybe? (Hope hope hope)

Comment: can you add info on what strings you have configured to match on, and then a pcap dump of the SSH connections you are making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a different port than default?

My guess is that fail2ban reads /etc/services and in that file your ssh is listed as 22.

Comment: This was close.  Turns out I was using a non-default logging location...  Go figure.